# How to pass a custom login failed notification to the view in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validationmessage

I want to pass an error login notification in the view which I coded my self, but I do not know how. I want to put it in the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)` or a separate label (am I correct that I will use `@Html.ValidationMessage()` instead of `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`?)

here is my model:

```
public class User 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User p)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User item = db.Authenticate(p);

        if (item != null) // if item is not null, the login succeeded
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Main", "Home");
        }
    }
    string error = "Incorrect user name or password."; //  I don't know how to pass this
    return View(); //login failed
}
```

here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the custom error message to the Model state dictionary using the `AddModelError` method. The `validationSummary` /`ValidationMessageFor` helper methods reads the validation errors from model state dictionary when it gets called.

The first parameter is the key for the error message. If you pass `string.empty` as the value the custom error message you are passing will be rendered by the `ValidationSummary` helper method

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Incorrect user name or password.");
return View(p);
```

If you want to render the error message by the input element (The one `ValidationMessageFor` renders), you may pass the property name as the key value when calling the `AdddModelError` method.

```
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(User.Password),"Incorrect password");
return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use AddModelError method for handling custom error message

```
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(User.UserName),"Incorrect UserName");
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(User.Password),"Incorrect password");
return View();
```